# Getting attributes in django

Tags: python, django

This might be a dumb question but how do pull attributes in Django?

I'm trying to write a view that pulls the "body" attribute from AboutBio

```
from django.db import models

class AboutBio(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=144)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

# Create your models here.
```

Comment: I recommend looking at the tutorial to django, basically you need to create a view and a template

Comment: [The documentation on querysets might help](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score -1):

To get `body` from `AboutBio` model:

```
AboutBio._meta.get_field('body')
```

From the [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/meta/)